# Tengo un select form que no muestra el dato seleccionado

Tags: html, nodejs, angular, select

Estoy trabajando con angular y nodejs, el problema es que estoy haciendo una pagina para reservar una habitacion y tengo un select en donde estan las habitaciones disponbles, la cosa es que cuando selecciono una habitacion no me muestra el dato en el select pero si lo manda a nodejs, porque si me hace la reservacion [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo de html es este `

```
<div class="mb-3" class="container">
    <label for="inputHabitacion" class="form-label">Habitacion</label>
    <select type="textarea" class="form-select" name="habitacion" #habitacion="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="reservacionModel.habitacion">
    <option selected></option>
    <option *ngFor="let hotel of _hotelesService.getHotel().habitaciones">{{hotel.nombreHabitacion}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row" class="col-5" class="container">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Fecha de entrada</label>
    <input id="date" type="date" class="form-control" value="2021-01-01" name="fechaEntrada" #fechaEntrada="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="reservacionModel.fechaEntrada">
</div>
<br>
<div class="mb-3" class="container">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">fecha de Salida</label>
    <input id="date" type="date" class="form-control" value="2021-01-01" name="fechaSalida" #fechaSalida="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="reservacionModel.fechaSalida">
</div>
<br>

<div class="mb-3" class="container">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="hacerReservacion()">Reservar</button>
</div>
```

`

el error sucede cuando le  coloco esto al select `name="habitacion" #habitacion="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="reservacionModel.habitacion"` pero no sé cómo hacer que me muestre el dato al seleccionarlo porque si le quito eso si muestra la habitacion seleccionada pero no puedo enviar el dato a nodejs

Answer (score 0):

agrega el value a tu option:

```
    <option *ngFor="let hotel of _hotelesService.getHotel().habitaciones" [value]="hotel.valorAEnviarBackend">{{hotel.nombreHabitacion}}</option>
```